# Does joomla/jomsocial provides webservices/API to their core functionality?

Tags: web-services, api, cordova, joomla, jomsocial

I am developing mobile apps using phonegap.

My mobile app will have same functionality as like my joomla-jomsocial website.

I have to access web services using jQuery.ajax as I am using javascript and html only.

Are there any ready web services or APIs in joomla-jomsocial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla! only recently formed a working group for "[Web Services](http://docs.joomla.org/Web_Services_Working_Group)" and I think you won't see any outcomes from that for a while.

As @Riccardo Zom, say your best bet will be to access the barest formats you can from each component type using the `format`/`tmpl` parameters.

If you're motivated enough you could extend existing components (core and otherwise) to return the desired format (e.g. `json`), in that case you should read [Louis Landry's note on the changes from 1.5 era `XML-RPC` feature set to the 1.6/2.5 mechanism.](http://docs.joomla.org/Xml-rpc_changes_in_Joomla!_1.6)

If you're still looking after that you may be interested in the "[Joomla! API - Generic RESTful API framework for Joomla! 2.5](https://github.com/rcorral/com_api)" by Rafael Corral, it's a component (`com_api`) that provides a framework for creating a RESTful API for a Joomla! 2.5 site.

Comment: Yes I am using `com_api` for creating RESTful APIs. But I am afraid that as I am using core functionality of joomla-jomsocial in my APIs. Will my API work, when I upgrade joomla-jomsocial version?

Comment: There's no guarantee that an update won't cause problems but they would only likely in major steps.  Of course this is what the Web Services group is working towards solving...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to rewrite the whole component logic in your html app, you might be happy with grabbing the component output without all the extra page markup i.e. get the bare html returned from the component: just add &format=raw to the query; if you want libraries and css to be returned as well, instead add &tmpl=component

There is also (limited) support for &format=json in some core components.